# Entity Framework one to optional foreign key code first fluent mapping

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, mapping, entity-framework-6

**Tables**

```
    User
    ------
    UserId   PK


    Access
    -------
    AccessId  PK
    UserId    FK to User.UserId
```

**User Entity**

```
public int Id { get; set; } 
public virtual Access Access { get; set; }
```

**Access Entity**

```
public int Id { get; set; } 
public int UserId { get; set; } 
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

**Access Mapping**

```
...  
HasKey(t => t.Id);
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("AccessId");
HasRequired(t => t.User).WithOptional(t => t.Access);
...
```

**User Mapping**

```
...
HasKey(t => t.Id);
Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
...
```

**Query**

```
var access = _unitOfWork.Users.Get()
                .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                .Select(u => u.Access)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Generated SQL**

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Access] AS [Extent2] 
   ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[AccessId] <-- ** PROBLEM IS HERE **
```

My query is attempting to join on the wrong column, even though I have PK/FK set up in the database and PKs specified on my entity maps. Can anyone spot what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When mapping a 1..0 or 1 relationship in EF, the dependent relationship is expected to have its primary key be the foreign key of the principal.

In your case, this means that your `Access` entity should drop the `AccessId` primary key and make the `UserId` be your key.

If you can't change your schema to allow this, your best bet for a workaround will have to be making the relationship a 1..many and fudging it in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much I was really stuck on this.

Comment: Does the same answer apply for an optional-to-optional relationship? The problem is that the "keyless" entity is supposed to have two separate optional-to-optional relationships, so the "keyless" entity can't use the principal's PK as its own PK... (concrete example: both a Person and a Car can _optionally_ have a Picture. A Picture is expected to be related to a Car or a Person, but never both. A Picture missing both a car and a person is a "don't care" situation, we don't need it but we can deal with having it if necessary).